# Mule 4 - How to do error handling inside a cache scope?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I'm using cache scope and object store to cache data returned from a Salesforce Query using Salesforce Connector.

I've added `On error continue` to catch any Salesforce Connector exceptions.

If there is an exception in Salesforce Connector (like `Salesforce Connectivity`), the application throws an exception and executes `On error continue` block, but when it is called again application hangs at the cache scope and doesn't give any response/error message. Also, `On error continue` block is executed thrice when the application is executed first time.

It's running fine in debug mode.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:os="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:salesforce="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce/current/mule-salesforce.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os/current/mule-os.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="6a5b02b3-836d-43b5-9dbe-41719d20258f" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <salesforce:sfdc-config name="Salesforce_Config" doc:name="Salesforce Config" doc:id="3facafa3-5d07-4717-901a-487f0cdeabb2" >
        <salesforce:basic-connection username="..." password="..." securityToken="..." url="https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/48.0" />
    </salesforce:sfdc-config>
    <ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Caching Strategy" doc:id="4ebcc02a-3c51-445b-bee5-0c95e4ce6e01" keyGenerationExpression="#['1']" >
        <os:private-object-store persistent="false" maxEntries="1" entryTtl="1" />
    </ee:object-store-caching-strategy>
    <flow name="test-errorFlow" doc:id="49520788-7379-45cb-9276-cdb6b268398c" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="ce5faf93-3153-4f93-8313-90d465f920c6" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/test" allowedMethods="GET">
            <http:response statusCode="#[vars.httpStatus]" />
            <http:error-response statusCode="#[vars.httpStatus]" >
                <http:body ><![CDATA[#[error]]]></http:body>
            </http:error-response>
        </http:listener>
        <ee:cache doc:name="Cache" doc:id="ae4e7d76-0f98-4202-9a51-59373ea3ee1c" cachingStrategy-ref="Caching_Strategy">
            <salesforce:query doc:name="Query" doc:id="1498398a-7b1f-4a27-aff8-3991d4e9cbca" config-ref="Salesforce_Config">
            <salesforce:salesforce-query><![CDATA[Select Id, Name from Account]]></salesforce:salesforce-query>
        </salesforce:query>
        </ee:cache>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="f864be76-86a9-4726-b1f1-586ffeabb0db" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <error-handler >
            <on-error-continue enableNotifications="true" logException="true" doc:name="On Error Continue" doc:id="038cd795-2174-4d9a-b759-2921dd12a64e" type="ANY">
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="186587c2-0beb-416a-b589-7239a2cba7dd" message="#[error]"/>
            </on-error-continue>
        </error-handler>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0):

'On error continue' means to finish flow even if error occurs. But finishing flow does not mean that it did its job - in particular cache value was not obtained. That's the reason the erst is failing.

Rearrange your flow - if cache value is null - run cache again and again ( for example https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/until-successful-scope ) and only success continue your regular flow with existing real cache value.

Comment: Thanks Alex for quick response. I am trying to handle the exception scenario. If Saleforce Connector throws an exception and cache value is null, application hangs when ran for the second time. It should throw the error instead. Can you please explain more about how this until successful block will help here?

Comment: I would suggest to move Query to another flow which you call by refernce. Inside this new flow you do Until Succeful that cache is not null and call Query inside it. I would actually move query to another flow which should have this On Error Continue handler.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that there is nothing to cache, because the error aborted the execution.

You can either use a [Try scope](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/try-scope-concept) to handle the error inside the Cache scope, or call to another flow with a flow-ref, and handle the error inside that other flow.

Example:

```
<ee:cache doc:name="Cache" cachingStrategy-ref="Caching_Strategy">
    <try>
        <salesforce:query doc:name="Query"  config-ref="Salesforce_Config">
            <salesforce:salesforce-query><![CDATA[Select Id, Name from Account]]></salesforce:salesforce-query>
        </salesforce:query>
        <error-handler>
            <on-error-continue>
                ....
            </on-error-continue>
        </error-handler>
    </try>
</ee:cache>
```

Comment: I'll add an example.

Comment: Thanks. Please add asap, need this urgently.

Comment: I added it. It is not a 'working example' but an example of how to use it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it

Comment: It returns error response, but also caches it. I tried using On error propagate but it is not working. Please suggest any alternative to solve this